# How to set up system path for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, irb

I am doing prep work for app academy. The final stage before I am done with my prep work is to complete a ruby intro course called "Test First Ruby".

The first line after you install Rspec is to enter the course directory. In the terminal it is "cd learn_ruby", simple enough, except it returns back a message that says "the system cannot find the path specified". I have been noticing this message on certain commands for all of my ruby learning thus far and I am just wondering what does this mean? And how can I fix this?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

`cd` means 'change directory'. The error you are getting is that the directory is not existant in the location your command line is in.

This looks like a reasonable intro to UNIX filesystem: http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~wjk/UnixIntro/Lecture2.html

UNIX reference: http://sunsite.utk.edu/UNIX-help/quickref.html

Answer (score 0):

Create the directory before you cd into it:

**mkdir learn_ruby**

**cd learn_ruby**

Do check out AJcodez's links to familiarize yourself with Unix filesystem commands.